# ReverseGraph confused by duplicate edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks

It appears duplicate edges confuse ReverseGraph
A simple example

`graph = Graph[{DirectedEdge[1,1],DirectedEdge[1,1],DirectedEdge[1,2]}, EdgeWeight->{Rule[DirectedEdge[1,2],-1}, VertexLabels->"Name", EdgeLabels->"EdgeWeight"]`

Yields the graph with weight -1 on the edge from 1 to 2.

[image: graph]

`ReverseGraph[graph]`

Yields the reversed graph but the edge weight -1 has been lost.

[image: reversegraph]

Without the duplicate edges:

`graph = Graph[{DirectedEdge[1,1],DirectedEdge[1,2]}, EdgeWeight->{Rule[DirectedEdge[1,2],-1}, VertexLabels->"Name", EdgeLabels->"EdgeWeight"]`

Yields

[image: graph-w-no-duplicate-edges]

and

`ReverseGraph[graph]`

Yields the reversed graph as expected:

[image: reverse-graph-no-duplicates]

Bug?

Comment: There are issues with graphs with duplicated edges regarding property inheritance. In this example the reversed graph doesn't inherit the edge weights because there are two identical edges.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or a limitation of the way edges were implemented. This was solved when edge tags were introduced recently, if you add a tag to each edge it becomes distinct.  Try `ReverseGraph[EdgeTaggedGraph[graph]]` and see if that works for you.

Comment: It is bug in labeling. If you look at full-form of reversed graph you will see that the weights are still set correctly `{1, 1, -1}` just labeling is wrong. So to me it is a bug.